# Change control's parent at runtime VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls, parent-child

I'm making a custom control that can be dragged around and it is semi transparent. I need it so that while it is moving (the mousemove event) that if it intersects a control that its parent becomes that control. I tried to have it iterate through all the controls and `if control.bounds.intersectswith me.clientrectangle then me.parent = control type` thing, but it did not work.  Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Would it be easier to do the assignment when the control is released rather than in mid-drag?

Comment: thats fine too, but how would i assign it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have references to both the original parent and the new parent, do the following:

```
OriginalParent.controls.remove(YourControl)

NewParent.controls.add(YourControl)
```

Comment: Or if you don't know the parent at design-time, `YourControl.Parent.Controls.Remove(YourControl) : NewParent.Controls.Add(YourControl)`. Moreover, the `Remove()` might not even be necessary. Edit: After checking [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,a984fc45e2486e83), yes, the `Remove` call is redundant as the `Add` method does it for you anyway.